# JQuery DateFormat Validation (Mon-YYYY)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to write a date format validation function through which I can validate the date which just carries month and year.The date is in the format (mon-yyyy) like Apr-2011 or any other.
I need to validate using jQuery.How to write such validation function?
                                      I have already have a date picker . I just want to know how to validate the form before submitting for the date format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852817/validation-of-invalid-date-leap-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Well, though this is a repeated question, 
//just to quench yo thirst, you can use javascript's RegExp for regular expressions.
//you can create one like:
var RegularExpression  =  new RegExp("pattern");
//or
var RegularExpression2  =  /pattern/;

//check for valid date format as:
var datePattern = /^\w{3}[-]\d{4}$/
//for numerical month value, u could use
//var datePattern = /^\d{1,2}[-]\d{4}$/
if(datePattern.test('my_date_string'))
   alert('correct')
else
   alert('false')

//or in a jquery way, if your date-holding element is an input with id as dateId
//then you can do:

if(datePattern.test($('#dateId').val()))
   alert('correct')
else
   alert('false')
```

Comment: Thanks !!! it worked. I wasnt able to find out the stuff so posted. Thanks anyways!! :)

Comment: good, accept an answer then :-) And by the way, incase you are validating for the sake of determining whether to submit a form or not, then to have more control, avoid the default type `submit` in the form's button, and instead use a custom function in the `onclick` parameter, in which function you can then chose to submit or not based on whether the fields pass the validation patterns. you can submit your form using jquery -- left as an exercise if u dont know how :-)